# Undo an accidental rm -rf * on a macbook pro

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any free undelete software for the Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/107396/is-there-any-free-undelete-software-for-the-mac)

I accidentally typed rm -rf * in my root directory instead of the folder I had intended to.

I managed to stop the delete halfway through, but it had already taken all my pictures, movies, music, and, most importantly, the 5000 odd lines of code that my advisor wants tonight.

I'm using a Macbook Pro, OSX 10.6.4
Any help recovering the stuff would be nice.

Thanks in advance.

PS I understand this may be a duplicate, but I'm asking before I start searching because I'm kinda desperate right now.

EDIT: Currently trying a program called StellarPhoenix for Mac.  Its finding stuff, no word on how successful it might be, though.

Comment: First: Stop using the partition, you may overwrite what's left of the files.

Comment: You're lucky it didn't find its way to your system files...

Comment: This has been asked before: http://superuser.com/questions/107396/is-there-any-free-undelete-software-for-the-mac

Comment: I'm asking with a bit of reservation, but none of this can be recovered from a recent backup, can it?

Comment: @fideli I reformatted my computer after graduating and until last week there was nothing of value on the machine.  Great way to start a new job, eh?  Glad I'm only a temp.

Comment: @mechko: True. Hopefully you can get your 5000 lines of code back. I haven't had great experience with data recovery in the past.

Comment: So I ran three or four different data recovery programs and got lucky with one of the classes, saving me about 6 hours in recovery work.  Consolidated my hard-drives and am currently setting up time machine.

*sniff* at least boss don't want it tomorrow any more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used photorec to good effect. You need to immediately stop using the drive at all, since it can begin to overwrite the data that was in the files. Mount the drive read-only using a livecd or another computer. I think with a mac you want to use target mode to hook it up to another.

Also, learn a lesson from this and start keeping backups of your valuable data. It could just as easily have been physical failure and then you'd not even have a chance of recovering anything.